# Objects holding values. I need to add five tests to my objects

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Course[] csharp = new Course[5];     

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Test c1 = new Test("Quiz",
            new DateTime(2012, 6, 6), 86);
        Test c2 = new Test("Mid-Term",
           new DateTime(2012, 5, 6), 90);
        Test c3 = new Test("Final",
           new DateTime(2012, 4, 6), 87);
        Test c4 = new Test("Quiz",
           new DateTime(2012, 3, 6), 100);
        Test c5 = new Test("Quiz",
           new DateTime(2012, 2, 6), 66);
    }
}
```

How do I add my test c5 to my object array csharp? i want to add five tests types to three objects. Pls help I'm on the beginner level.

Comment: You cannot add an object of the type `Test` to an array of the type `Course`.

Comment: i need to fill course object with five tests while using my test class that has three fields.

Comment: How should we be able to tell you how to add `Test` objects to a `Course` object when you haven't showed us the definition for the `Course` class? You need to clean up your question: improve your language, add relevant code (`Course` class definition for instance), and remove irrelevant code (like the `Form1()` constructor). I'd also recommend reading this: http://bit.ly/PerfectQuestion

Answer (score 3):

You can declare an array and assign a value to it using the [array initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) as follows:

```
Test[] tests = {
    new Test("Quiz", new DateTime(2012, 6, 6), 86),
    new Test("Mid-Term", new DateTime(2012, 5, 6), 90),
    new Test("Final", new DateTime(2012, 4, 6), 87),
    new Test("Quiz", new DateTime(2012, 3, 6), 100),
    new Test("Quiz", new DateTime(2012, 2, 6), 66)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand I was a beginner and had questions just like this! You cant add a Test Object, to A Course Object, they are two different things!

You need something like

```
  Test[] courseTests = new Test[5];
```

And add by doing

```
   courseTests[1] = new Test("Quiz", new DateTime(2012, 6, 6), 86);
```

---

Or you can use a list `List<Test> courseTests = new List<Test>();` and use courseTests.Add

---

Edit:

I see what you mean, You need something like this:

```
public Class course
{
    public List<Test> tests = new List<Test>();
     //Place other course code here
}
public Class Test
{
   public string Name;
   public Datetime Time;
   public int Number;
    Test(string name, Datetime time, int number)
    {
Name = name;
Time = time;
Number = number;
    }
}
```

And then in your Main method or whatever, do `Course.tests.Add(new Test(Blah blah blah));`

Comment: i am trying to add five tests which i have another class for the type, date and grade and add those five to a course object

Comment: there is no T[].Add(T) method. I think you mean to use `List<T>` here, or just direct index access on the array, i.e. T[_index_] = value;

Comment: Then in that case, You need to add a List of tests.inside the course class. So you have a course class that owns the test class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Test[] in your Course class set to the size that you want. Then create a void method like this. In the code below myTests is your test array. Hope this helps!

```
    public void addTest(Test a)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < myTests.Length; i++)
       {
           if (myTests[i] == null)
           {
               //Adds test and leaves loop.
               myTests[i] = a;
               break;
           }
           //Handler for if all tests are already populated.
           if (i == myTests.Length)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("All tests full.");
           }
        }
    }
```

Also, if you want to make the size of your test array dynamic you could use an ArrayList. Hope this helps!

Comment: You can call this method from an instance of a Course.